# Get the count of currently active windows in the current Activity and Virtual Desktop?

Tags: kde-plasma, xdotool, virtual-desktop, task-switching

There is a bug in KDE Activities where windows do not get focused and this requires to press Alt+Tab to switch to the last active window.

I want to count the number of the windows to press only when there is some, I tried

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --desktop 2 --name ''
```

but it gets all the desktops in all the activities, I want to get the desktops in the current activity only

Answer (score 0):

The current desktop number can be found using

```bash
xdotool get_desktop
```

You can mix this with your command to find the windows in the current active desktop

```bash
xdotool search --desktop $(xdotool get_desktop) --class ''
```

Then to get the count by piping the result into `wc` tool as lines

```
xdotool search --desktop $(xdotool get_desktop) --class '' | wc -l
```